# Ludo game with talkative output

Tags: python-3.x, random

I need to make Ludo game of 2 players, each player has 4 figures. The length of the board is 12. The output needs to be in talkative mode:

```
Blue, out: 4, home line: . | . | . | . (home starts before 1)
Red , out: 4, home line: . | . | . | . (home starts before 7)
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
```

Indicating which player throws the dice and what number came out and the move of each figure on the plan, for example:

```
Red throws 6 (cannot move)

Blue, out: 3, home line: . | . | . | . (home starts before 1)
Red , out: 3, home line: . | . | . | . (home starts before 7)
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 
.  .  B1 .  .  .  R1 .  .  .  .  .  

Red throws 5

Blue, out: 3, home line: . | . | . | . (home starts before 1)
Red , out: 3, home line: . | . | . | . (home starts before 7)
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 
.  .  B1 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  R1
```

I have managed to get the talkative form but I have problems with the movements of the figures, to be exact with putting the figures on their start positions and then their movement:

```
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 
B1 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
-----------------------------------
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 
.  .  B1 .  .  .  R1 .  .  .  .  .
-----------------------------------
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 
B2 .  .  B1 .  .  .  .  .  .  .  R1
-----------------------------------
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 
.  B3 .  .  .  R2 .  .  .  .  .  .
etc.
```

and their placement into the home, marked by home line where dot indicates free spot and * indicates that figure is already there:

```
Red throws 3

Blue, out: 2, home line: . | . | . | . (home starts before 1)
Red , out: 3, home line: . | . | . | . (home starts before 7)
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 
B2 .  .  .  .  R1 .  .  B1 .  .  .  

Blue throws 4

Blue, out: 2, home line: * | . | . | . (home starts before 1)
Red , out: 3, home line: . | . | . | . (home starts before 7)
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 
B2 .  .  .  .  R1 .  .  .  .  .  .
```

and combine it with the dice, which I need to throw at least 3 times till 6 won't come out:

```
def throw_dice():
    r = randint(1,6)
    is r == 6 or r == 6 or r == 6:
        return randint(1,6)
    return r
```

Can anyone help me, please? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, your question isn't really answerable, as you haven't described a specific problem. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips on asking.

Comment: Hi! This sounds like a fun project, but I'm not sure what exactly you need help with. Have a look at the [help] and think about some *specific* things you'd like help with.